# Can't install kobuki

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I go through this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation). In 2.3.2 I run this command:

`wstool init src -j5 https://raw.github.com/yujinrobot/yujin_tools/master/rosinstalls/indigo/kobuki.rosinstall`

I have an error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git version indigo into /home/nadya/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs failed.

ERROR in config: Error processing 'yocs_msgs' : [yocs_msgs] Checkout of https://github.com/yujinrobot/yocs_msgs.git version indigo into /home/nadya/kobuki/src/yocs_msgs failed.
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223127/can%27t-install-kobuki/) by [nampi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24910/nampi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2015-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a problem with github's service. I suspect that if you try again it will work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1